# Access singleton class methods in blackberry 10

Tags: c++, singleton, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I have implemented Singleton class method hpp and cpp like the following

Singleton.hpp

```
    class Singleton {
private:
    Singleton();

public:
    virtual ~Singleton();
    static Singleton &instance();

    int getMemberField();
    void setMemberField(int mf);

private:
    static Singleton    *p_instance;

    int                 m_memberField;
};
```

Singleton.cpp

```
Singleton* Singleton::p_instance=NULL ;

Singleton::Singleton() {
    p_instance = this;
    m_memberField = 0;
}

Singleton::~Singleton() {
    p_instance = NULL;
}

Singleton&    Singleton::instance() {
    if (p_instance==NULL) {
        p_instance = new Singleton();
    }
    return *p_instance;
}
int Singleton::getMemberField(){
    return m_memberField;
}

void Singleton::setMemberField(int mf){
     m_memberField = mf;
}
```

My problem is how to access those methods either set or get in application classes.
Please help,

Comment: `p_instance = this;` this line is not needed because you do `p_instance = new Singleton();` in `instance()`

Comment: Lets suppose that you do this to get the instance "Singleton *s = Singleton::instance(), then you can just call it like s->set() and s->get()

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you are having problems with?

Comment: @Saran-san: note that his singleton is returning a ``Singleton``, not ``Singleton*``.

Comment: @kernald: you are right!! Sorry, missed that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Singleton::instance().setMemberField(42);
```